# oracle order by optimization

Tags: oracle, indexing, sql-order-by

I am running a query on a large table and I am expecting a large number of returning row.
unfortunately I need to order the result by 2 columns, which makes the query quite slow.

I added an index to those specific columns but was wondering, if the order direction makes a difference.
one column is ordered desc and one is order asc.

thanks and best wishes,
e.

Comment: hi Ele - The index tells the database which blocks on the filesystem need to be fetched - that way it speeds up data retrieval. I don't think the index will speed up later processing (for example ordering the data).  I don't think the direction of the order by will make any difference at all.  Obviously the order by clause cannot do its thing until all data has been retrieved (the final row to come off the filesytem might be the first you want to see).  You will see a delay before any data is returned

Comment: Hi @ChristianPalmer, I read quite a lot of articles, where it is recommended to create an index with the same parameters as your order by, because the index will order the data already in the correct way. looking at the execution plan of a simple example underlines the thesis e.g. https://use-the-index-luke.com/de/sql/sortieren-gruppieren/indexed-order-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query **might** benefit from an index ordered the same way as your `order by` clause e.g.

```
create index index1 on table1 (col1 desc, col2 asc);
```

Whether it will benefit depends on the relative cost of the index scans and table lookups versus a simple full table scan.  If the number of rows you want is low relative to the total number of rows in the table the query **might** benefit.

The only way to know for sure is try it.